# Laravel - Get price of product in seeder with ID

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to seed my database. And currently, I'm trying to get the price of a product that has the ID of `$index`. My seeder looks like this.

```
foreach(range(1,25) as $index)
    {
        DB::table('orderitems')->insert([

            'order_id' => rand(1, 25),
            'product_id' => $index,
            'price' => '',
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),

        ]);
    }
```

I foreach this seed 25 times. What I'm trying to achieve is to get the price of each product with the given id. Say, for instance, product_id is 10. I want the price of the product with the ID 10. The relations are fine. I can do something like $product->price and it works fine. How can I achieve this?

the database looks like this

```
Products
    name
    description
    price
    period
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it works fine like you said, what exactly do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get product price by product id using query like code given as bellow:

```
foreach(range(1,25) as $index)
    {
        $product = DB::table("products")->where('id',$index)->first();
        DB::table('orderitems')->insert([

            'order_id' => rand(1, 25),
            'product_id' => $index,
            'price' => $product->price,
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),

        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 'price' => Product::where('id',$index)->first()->price,
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$range = range(1,25);
$productIds = Product::whereIn('id', $range)->pluck('price', 'id');    

foreach($range as $index)
{
        DB::table('orderitems')->insert([    
            'order_id' => rand(1, 25),
            'product_id' => $index,
            'price' => $productIds[$index] ?? null,
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),

        ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way.

```
foreach(range(1,25) as $index)
    {        
        $price = App\Products::->find($index)->price;
        DB::table('orderitems')->insert([
            'order_id' => rand(1, 25),
            'product_id' => $index,
            'price' => $price,
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
        ]);
    }
```